# Draw an SVG rectangle with gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" on Canvas without using the built in transform function or changing the color stops?

Tags: svg, canvas, transform, linear-algebra, coordinate-transformation

Here is an SVG that has a linear gradient that uses objectBoundingBox gradientUnits:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="yellow" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="10" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
</svg>
```

I need to draw this on a Canvas.

I can draw the gradient on a Canvas if I use the transform method:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasBuiltInScale');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  ctx.save();

  // create a square 1x1 gradient
  const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 1,  1);
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, 'yellow');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'black');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'red');

  // scale it up to the size of the bbox
  const width = x1 - x0;
  const height = y1 - y0;

  ctx.transform(width, 0, 0, height, x0, y0);
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);  
  ctx.restore();
}

draw(10, 10, 40, 30);
```

But unfortunately the customer does not want me to use the transform method.

I can draw the same gradient on a Canvas with a home rolled scaling instead.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasHomeRolledScale');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  const width = x1-x0;
  const height = y1-y0;

  // The problem is that with userSpace coordinates, the normal to the gradient vector from x0,y0 to x1,y1 will not go between x1,y0 and x0,y1
  // I perform a home baked geometric calculation to find the normal vector to [x1-x0, y1-y0] since its normal vector will pass through [x1-x0, y1-y0]
  const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(
    x0 + (width - height) / 2, 
    y0 + (height - width) / 2, 
    x0 + (width - height) / 2 + height, 
    y0 + (height - width) / 2 + width
  );

  gradient.addColorStop(rescale(0.4), 'yellow');
  gradient.addColorStop(rescale(0.5), 'black');
  gradient.addColorStop(rescale(0.6), 'red');
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(x0, y0, width, height);

  // The normal vector calculated above has the right direction, but not the right amplitude.
  // Here I guy guessed that I could use pythagoras theorem to arrive at the correct scale
  function rescale(percent) {
    const max = Math.max(height, width)
    const min = Math.min(height, width)
    const f = (
      Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(max, 2) + Math.pow(min, 2)
      ) / 
      Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(max, 2) + Math.pow(max, 2)
      )
    );
    const midPoint = 0.5;
    return midPoint - (midPoint-percent) * f
  }
}

draw(10, 10, 40, 30);
```

But I am not allowed to change the percentage of the color stops.

**The objection in both cases has been the valid objection that there ought to be a simpler more elegant solution to this problem. Hence, I ask the intelligent people in here if there is a solution that:**

- Does not use the transform method
- Does not change the color stops

Comment: How is doing in a single  step what should be done not simple nor elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a transformation of coordinates, this would do the trick:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasBuiltInScale');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function tcoord(x0, y0, x1, y1){
  let xc = (x1 + x0) / 2;
  let yc = (y1 + y0) / 2;
  let dx = (x1 - x0) / 2;
  let dy = (y1 - y0) / 2;
  let rx0 = xc - dy;
  let ry0 = yc - dx;
  let rx1 = xc + dy;
  let ry1 = yc + dx;
  let result = [rx0,ry0,rx1,ry1];
  return result;
}

function draw(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  ctx.save();
  let c = tcoord(x0, y0, x0 + x1, y0 + y1);
  const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(c[0], c[1], c[2],  c[3]);
  gradient.addColorStop(0.4, 'yellow');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'black');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'red');
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(x0, y0, x1, y1);  
  ctx.restore();
}

draw(10, 10, 80, 60);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasBuiltInScale" width="300" height="300">
</canvas>
```

For what it is worth, I find your `transform` solution way more elegant.

*EDIT after comment*

It stands to reason that if we change the start and end points of the gradient, we also need to transform the gradient steps. I have forked the fiddle with a solution ( https://jsfiddle.net/ftadpu3c/3/ ). It uses a new function called `transformGradient`. Since this transformation depends on the first one, there is one parameter that is calculated in `tcoord`. I also changed the style a little bit to make it more consistent. The third and fourth parameters passed to `draw` are a width and a height, rather than coordinates.

**Edit 2**
I was caught up in the notion that the distance of the transformed points to the center of the rectangle had to be maintained. Of course, that is not true. By choosing a suitable distance, it will not be necessary to transform the gradient. See second fork at https://jsfiddle.net/uwshL43f/

Comment: I really like your solution. Thank you! But the gradient is not as long as in the original SVG, see that the black area is wider with your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/u4h8Lov9/ Can you think of any fix for that?

Comment: Yes, gradient steps also need a transformation. I have edited the answer and forked your fiddle.

Comment: Can the gradient be transformed differently (the amplitude of the vector adjusted) to avoid having to modifythe gradient stops?

Comment: Yes, easily. I was not thinking straight. I have updated the answer again.

Comment: By the way, there is no need to return `gtransform`, I forgot to take it out.

Comment: Thank you, that's just perfect

Comment: Do you think that you could generalize your function to handle linear gradients where x1, y1, x2, y2 can be arbitrary values? I have tried for to do that but have failed.

Comment: I think I did it, here: https://jsfiddle.net/dnLbk8tr/6/

Comment: Yes, I had seen the other question, but I did not have time to answer. As you note in the fiddle, the problem is different, since `objectBoundingBox` distorts the coordinate system.

Comment: The answers in this question solve all my problems. The only thing remaining ( jsfiddle.net/dnLbk8tr/6) is that I fail to draw a gradient that is not diagonal at all. For exmaple drawing a gradient using x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="1%" works fine, but changing y2 to "0%" causes the gradient to not draw. Feel extremely welcome to take a look if you have time. Regardless, I am  grateful for the time and expertise you have given .

Comment: The issue is in `const slope = (((fry2 - fry1) / (frx2 - frx1)) / ((y2-y1) / (x2-x1)));`. If `frx2 === frx2 || x2 === x1`, the result is not finite. You need to treat those cases separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw the SVG directly using drawImage:

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=100 height=100></canvas>

<script>
  function svgimage() {
    var image = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="myGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="yellow" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="red" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
</svg>`;
    return encodeURIComponent(image);
  }

  function drawImage() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }

  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = drawImage
  img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + svgimage();
</script>
```